# pulseaudio daemon not starting

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Hey guys my speaker suddenly stopped working and it looks like pulseaudio daemon is not starting and gives off dummy output.I have tried most of the ways mentioned in similar questions like this.Anyone got any clues.

```
pulseaudio -D
```

gets me this

> E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.

anyone can help!

Comment: You need some context. What OS you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution from ChatGPT and I haven't seen any type of this solution hope it helps someone.

Check if pulseaudio is running by `systemctl --user status pulseaudio`

If it is not active try `systemctl --user start pulseaudio`

Comment: Note that ChatGPT answers are not necessarily permitted here, whether you are directly posting it or not, because of an imposed ban currently on ChatGPT content.